# Import data from multiple csv data into one master table

Tags: php, sql, csv, import

I have a MySQL database on which i want to import data from multiple csv files. For the data I provided a table on which I want to merge the several files into one (join). Unfortunately I have the problem that my data is too big and therefore it is quite time-consuming until I get everything stored in the table. Therefore the question: What is the best way to deal with a huge amount of data?

I took the liberty to create a temporary table for each csv file and load the data into it. Then I joined all tables and wanted to insert the result of my query into the big table and there I already had the problem with the long waiting time. I would like to limit the solutions to the following languages: MySQL, PHP. So far I used the GUI of datagrip and the sql-console for importing these files.

Answer (score 2):

Use any data integration tool like Pentaho, then follow the below steps:

1. Pentaho has CSV import object
2. You could join multiple CSV file using join object
3. Select all the columns from merging output
4. Then push it to MySQL using DB connector output object

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty neat library that does exactly this. Helps you to migrate data from one source to another. And it does pretty quickly.

https://github.com/DivineOmega/uxdm

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shell script to loop through the files (this one assumes they're in the current directory)

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.csv

do

mysql -e "load data infile '"$f"' into table my_table" -u username --password=your_password my_database

done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with the use of **pentaho data integration (ETL tool)**. 
It provided us **csv data input** in which you can mention your csv file. then link to **table output** step in which you can use **jdbc or jndi connection** of your mysql database.